# First time to add facebook social plugins ( comment box )

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I'm trying to add a comment box to my asp.net project, but comments are not fitted to each post individually. I need a comment box for each post on my website. I've watched videos and tried to add the code generated from Facebook developers area to test that:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="my URL" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

It works for all the posts, but I need it to be for **each post**. Note that I'm using asp.net with C# if that helps.

Comment: I need different comment box appears to its related post